# Rails Create has_many_through won't create records

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, formtastic

I am creating an exercise tracking website that has a Workout table, a WorkoutExercise table, and an Exercise table (this is just some of the schema).

I have been trying to create a "WorkoutExercise" from the Edit / create Workout form. I'm using Formtastic and my form displays the list of exercises for the user, but when I submit the form, no WorkoutExercises get created, but the workout does get created or updated.

I've searched google and stackoverflow for this issue for a day and a half with not much help. From what I can tell, this should "just work", I think I've missed something simple. This is my first RoR website, so please bear with me:)

Another thing to note, if I manually create the relationship in PSQL, the exercises that I create a relation for show up checked, but when I hit submit, the WorkoutExercise records are deleted from the database.

Database Schema for these 3 tables:

```
  create_table "exercises", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.text     "notes"
    t.decimal  "base_weight"
  end

  create_table "workout_exercises", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "workout_id"
    t.integer  "exercise_id"
    t.integer  "exercise_order"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "workouts", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "name"
  end
```

Exercise Model:

```
class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :weight_logs, dependent: :destroy
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :workout_exercises
   has_many :workouts, :through => :workout_exercises
   ...
```

WorkoutExercise Model (Many to many table)

```
class WorkoutExercise < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :exercise
    belongs_to :workout
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :workout
    #default_scope -> { order('exercise_order ASC') }
    validates :exercise_id, presence: true
    validates :workout_id, presence: true
    validates :exercise_order, presence: true
end
```

Workout Model:

```
class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :workout_exercises
    has_many :exercises, :through => :workout_exercises, :class_name => 'Exercise'
    belongs_to :user
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :exercises
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :workout_exercises
    ...
```

Workouts_conroller.rb

```
class WorkoutsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_workout, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :correct_user, only: :destroy
  # GET /workouts
  # GET /workouts.json
  def index
    @workouts = Workout.all
  end

  # GET /workouts/1
  # GET /workouts/1.json
  def show
  end

  def add_exercise
  end
  # GET /workouts/new
  def new
    @workout = current_user.workouts.new
    @exercises = current_user.exercises.all

  end

  # GET /workouts/1/edit
  def edit
    @exercises = @workout.exercises.build
  end

  # POST /workouts
  # POST /workouts.json
  def create
    @workout = current_user.workouts.build(workout_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @workout.save
        format.html { redirect_to @workout, notice: 'Workout was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @workout }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @workout.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /workouts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /workouts/1.json
  def update
   respond_to do |format|
     if @workout.update(workout_params)
       format.html { redirect_to @workout, notice: 'Workout was successfully updated.' }
       format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @workout }
     else
       format.html { render :edit }
       format.json { render json: @workout.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
  end

  # DELETE /workouts/1
  # DELETE /workouts/1.json
  def destroy
    @workout.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to workouts_url, notice: 'Workout was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_workout
      @workout = Workout.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def workout_params
      params.require(:workout).permit(:description, :name,
                        :exercise_ids => [:exercise_id])
    end

    def correct_user
        @workout = current_user.workouts.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @workout.nil?
    end
end
```

Rails Server log on Save:

```
Started PATCH "/workouts/6" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-13 19:30:05 -0700
Processing by WorkoutsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"v", "authenticity_token"=>"WY2P1Z7/g/PoG5iB6VufDNOG7Hyk7tnJQzTT00CpNTM=", "workout"=>{"name"=>"sad", "description"=>"asd", "exercise_ids"=>["", "17", "23",
"9", "15", "14", "18"]}, "commit"=>"Update Workout", "id"=>"6"}
  ?[1m?[36mWorkout Load (0.0ms)?[0m  ?[1mSELECT  "workouts".* FROM "workouts"  WHERE "workouts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1?[0m  [["id", 6]]
  ?[1m?[35mUser Load (1.0ms)?[0m  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  ?[1m?[36m (0.0ms)?[0m  ?[1mBEGIN?[0m
  ?[1m?[35mExercise Load (0.0ms)?[0m  SELECT "exercises".* FROM "exercises" INNER JOIN "workout_exercises" ON "exercises"."id" = "workout_exercises"."exercise_id" WHERE "workout_ex
ercises"."workout_id" = $1  ORDER BY name ASC  [["workout_id", 6]]
  ?[1m?[36m (0.0ms)?[0m  ?[1mCOMMIT?[0m
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/workouts/6
```

And here's my form too:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @workout do |f| %>
  <%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
    <%= f.input :exercises, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => Exercise.where(:user_id => @workout.user_id) %>
  <% end%>

  <%= f.actions %>
<% end %>
```

**EDIT**
I'm unable to answer my question, but I've found a workaround. I don't think this is the best solution, but it works! This was added in the def update of my workouts_controller.rb

```
 if @workout.update(workout_params)
        params[:workout].each do |key,value|
            if key == 'exercise_ids'
                @exercises = Exercise.find(value.reject!{|a| a==""})
                @workout.exercises << @exercises        
            end
        end
```

Comment: Try to get the code working on Rails console before involving the views.  Take this quiz on many_to_many relationships: http://www.codequizzes.com/learn-rails/many-to-many-relationships  From your server log, it looks like the WorkoutsController#update action is being fired, so I wouldn't expect a new record to be created.

Comment: Do I need to create a view and controller for WorkoutExercises to accomplish this? I'll take a look at the quiz.

Comment: I'm unable to answer my own question, but here is what I did to to make this work: